# Getting date with timezone offset

Tags: postgresql, date, timestamp, timezone

I am trying to extract the date from a query in postgres. The timestamp is stored as UTC, so if I have 1/1/2014 02:00:00, I want the date in pacific time, to be 12/31/2013, not 1/1/2014. I am really close, but both query 2 and 3 still return 1/1/2014.

```
SELECT '1-1-2014 02:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Los_Angeles';
```

returns

```
2014-01-01 02:00:00-08
```

-

```
SELECT CAST('1-1-2014 02:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Los_Angeles' AS Date);
```

returns

```
2014-01-01
```

but I want it to return `2013-12-31`.

```
SELECT CAST('1-1-2014 00:02:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Los_Angeles' AS Date) at time zone 'America/Los_Angeles';
```

returns

```
2014-01-01 00:00:00
```

but I want it to return `2013-12-31 00:00:00`

I basically want to return the date in the timezone it is in, in this case the pacific timezone.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If it is timestamp without time zone you need first to tell it to use the UTC time zone and then convert to another time zone:

```
SELECT '1-1-2014 02:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'America/Los_Angeles';
      timezone       
---------------------
 2013-12-31 18:00:00
```

Comment: Be careful with this solution if your client time zone is different from your server time zone. The timestamp value will be implicitly assigned your client time zone and then *converted* to 'UTC' as written. To avoid this, rewrite the first conversion as ::timestamp without time zone at time zone 'UTC'

Answer (score 7):

If `'America/Los_Angeles'` is your current time zone (`timezone` setting of the current session) then just tell Postgres the time zone of the `timestamp`.

```
SELECT ('2014-01-01 02:00:00'::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::date;
```

The cast to `date` is based on the current time zone and works automatically as desired.

If the current time zone can be something else, you need to be explicit [like @Clodoaldo demonstrates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22997673/939860).

The **proper solution** would be to store a `timestamp with time zone` (`timestamptz`) to begin with, then you can just cast to `date`:

```
SELECT '2014-01-01 02:00:00+0'::timestamptz::date;
```

About timestamps in Postgres:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

Recent related answer with more details (also dealing with indexes):

- [Optimize/Index Timezone Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22920107/optimize-index-timezone-query/22920810#22920810)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, using the interval, I can subtract the offset and then get the date.

```
SELECT '1-1-2014 02:00:00'::timestamp + INTERVAL '1 hour' * extract(timezone_hour FROM '1-1-2014 00:02:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Los_Angeles');
```

Adding the answer here, since I am sure this question might be something others would want to know.

Comment: This doesn't take day light savings into account.