# ActiveRecord query on dates in user's time zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, timezone, rails-activerecord

I'm having querying objects on the same date relative to the user (ie if it is 2016-11-11 in the user's time zone, they should see events that occur on 11-11 in their time zone).

My database stores the event datetimes (of type datetime) in UTC.  When I try:

`Event.where(DATE(datetime) = ?", Time.zone.today)`

I expect it to pull events where the datetime is on the same date as the current user's timezone (which is set in an `around_action` via `Time.use_zone`).  I have this set in application.rb:

`config.active_record.time_zone_aware_types = [:datetime, :time]`

However, events that are stored in the next day UTC are not being returned.  For example, an event at 11/11 10PM Mountain Time is stored at 11/12 5AM in UTC. It should still be returned to the Mountain Time user as happening on 11/11.

How do I query the database to get events for the current user's date?  Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to this question I found an answer:

[Getting date with timezone offset in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22996959/getting-date-with-timezone-offset-in-postgres)

I basically needed to convert the datetime to UTC **first**, then to the user time zone.

`Event.where("DATE(datetime AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE ?) = ?", Time.now.in_time_zone(current_user.time_zone).strftime("%Z"), Time.zone.today)`

Comment: How would I do this if I want to get user date and time depending on time zones? Using your example I want 11/11 10PM again on querying. 

I changed Time.zone.today to Time.zone.now to get current datetime