# Postgres count by date with timezone

Tags: postgresql, timezone

I want to query a table to find out a count of objects created by date, day and month in Postgres.

***Fetch count for last 30 days***

```
SELECT d.date, count(se.id)
FROM (SELECT to_char(date_trunc('day', (current_date - offs)), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS date 
FROM generate_series(0, 30) AS offs) d LEFT OUTER JOIN
     someTable se 
     ON d.date = to_char(date_trunc('day', se.created_at), 'YYYY-MM-DD')  
GROUP BY d.date;
```

***Fetch count by day***

```
select to_char(created_at,'day') as Day,
       extract(month from created_at) as Date,
       count("id") as "Count"
from someTable
group by 1,2
```

***Fetch count by month***

```
select to_char(created_at,'Mon') as mon,
       extract(year from created_at) as yyyy,
       count("id") as "Count"
from someTable
group by 1,2
```

This works fine for me. The problem that I have is, I want the data to be fetched based on different timezones. I have stored the time in `UTC`. I would be able to run these queries with different timezones.

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22997673/2193672) to get the datetime in Postgres with different timezone.

***Fetch count for last 30 days***

```
SELECT d.date, count(se.id)
FROM (SELECT to_char(date_trunc('day', (current_date - offs)), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS date 
FROM generate_series(0, 30) AS offs) d LEFT OUTER JOIN
     someTable se 
     ON d.date = to_char(date_trunc('day', se.created_at::timestamp with time zone at time zone 'EST'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')  
GROUP BY d.date;
```

***Fetch count by day***

```
select to_char(created_at::timestamp with time zone at time zone 'EST','day') as Day,
       extract(month from created_at) as Date,
       count("id") as "Count"
from someTable
group by 1,2
```

***Fetch count by month***

```
select to_char(created_at::timestamp with time zone at time zone 'EST','Mon') as mon,
       extract(year from created_at) as yyyy,
       count("id") as "Count"
from someTable
group by 1,2
```

Also refer to this Postgres [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) to learn about timezone with datetime.